# TBB: Possible to get Thread IDs?

Tags: c++, tbb

I have a very simple parallel_for loop

```
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, values.size()),
    [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r)
    {
        for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
        {
            values[i] = std::sin(i * 0.001);
        }
    });
```

Where 'values' is a vector of doubles. What I'd like to know is which threads work on which range in the loop. Is it possible to get a thread ID of some kind from TBB?

Comment: shouldn't std::this_thread::get_id() just work?

Comment: I don't think so, at least per this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506336

Comment: Well, that what I was reading" Replacement -> std::thread means "std::thread::get_id() should behave as expected from wherever it is called." (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/392381)

Comment: Ah, I must’ve misread it, then. My apologies.

Comment: If you're dealing with quite fresh TBB installation you could try to call it and see how it is going. If it works, just post it as your own answer, I would happily endorse it, it is useful to know that it is working solution. I don't have anything with TBB right now, couldn't test myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also, if you want to know a relative number of worker thread in current [task_arena](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler/task_arena_cls.html), which goes from 0 to the arena concurrency level, use this:

```
int worker_index = tbb::task_arena::current_thread_index();
```

The range of index values can be contiguous if all the threads will get to work at the same time.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, the "IDs" make much more sense.

Comment: This works well, also tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency() is useful in combination with current_thread_index to get the maximum number of threads that may run to setup per-thread storage

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the solution is to use

```
tbb::this_tbb_thread::get_id()
```

in tbb_thread.h. See this for more details:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506336